# random access iterator's complexity

Tags: c++, iterator, time-complexity

I want to check whether the iterating over an array of n elements has a complexity O(n)? To fight against the compiler optimizations, I initialize the array by {-1,1,-1,1...} then compute the sum of all elements. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const int numIter = 1000;
chrono::system_clock::time_point getTime()
{
    return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}
void showDeltaT( const string& text, const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& t1, std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& t2 )
{
    cout <<
        text <<
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count() <<
        " milliseconds" <<
        "\n"
        ;
}
void test( int size )
{
    cout << "test for size  " << size << "\n";
    std::vector<int> array( size );
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        array[i] = i % 2 ? 1 : -1;
    }
    auto t1 = getTime();
    int s = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < numIter; i++ )
    {
        for ( int k = 0; k < size; k++ )
        {
            s += array[k];
        }
    }
    auto t2 = getTime();
    showDeltaT( "the sum is: " + to_string( s ) + " and the time is ", t1, t2 );
    cout << endl;

}
void main()
{
    test( ( int )1.e6 );
    test( ( int )2.e6 );
    test( ( int )3.e6 );
    test( ( int )4.e6 );
    test( ( int )5.e6 );
    test( ( int )6.e6 );
    test( ( int )7.e6 );
    test( ( int )8.e6 );
    test( ( int )9.e6 );
    test( ( int )10.e6 );
    getchar();
}
```

Suprisingly I didn't get the desired result. It seems the time increases nonlinearly:

test for size  1000000
the sum is: 0 and the time is 121 milliseconds

test for size  2000000
the sum is: 0 and the time is 316 milliseconds

test for size  3000000
the sum is: 0 and the time is 580 milliseconds

test for size  4000000
the sum is: 0 and the time is 828 milliseconds

test for size  5000000
the sum is: 0 and the time is 1063 milliseconds

test for size  6000000
the sum is: 0 and the time is 1285 milliseconds

test for size  7000000
the sum is: 0 and the time is 1521 milliseconds

test for size  8000000
the sum is: 0 and the time is 1756 milliseconds

test for size  9000000
the sum is: 0 and the time is 1998 milliseconds

test for size  10000000
the sum is: 0 and the time is 2260 milliseconds

Can you explain such a behavior?

UPDATE:
As was mentioned in the comments, the dependency is actually linear. Yes it is true:
[image]

Now the new question arises: why its prolongation doesn't pass (0,0)?

Comment: That looks pretty linear to me. Did you graph it?

Comment: I put the figures into LibreOffice and made a chart: http://imagebin.ca/v/2YkHiaGEjfLr

Comment: @Galik thank you. You are right. Please see the update of the question

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the time resolution (milliseconds) is way to small to be precise. Any "contamination" from the exterior (the OS executing some other tasks) derails the results... Try with something more demanding and please get the execution time for more than a run for the same test (like three times for 100k elements and then do a mean). If you really want to measure performance take a look at this example:

http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~teodores/download/teaching/cse675.au08/CSE675.02.Performance.pdf